# Order between the section and the name

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In my project I created sections to separate the exercises created by this code:

```
private func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController { 
    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: cargaFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath:"exercicio.nome", cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultController
}
```

And titleForHeaderInSection in my code looked like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String! { 
    return self.fetchedResultController.sections[section].name 
}
```

I create the exercise, eg bench press. It saves and creates Supino Supino section. However, if I then create the legpress exercise, it creates legpress section, but the section is legpress Supino Supino and in section legpress.That is, it seems to be randomly creating. How to fix it?

Comment: Try logging your fetched results array and see what you have, your data source might be incorrect, as the code looks OK.

Comment: The strange thing is that I change my sectionNameKeyPath by "exercicio.meta" and he orders the sections with their names correctly!